# Guiders.js attachTo not working inside iframe

Tags: javascript, guiders.js

I am using [guiders.js](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS) to gives tips to users.
Though I have a problem using the attachTo parameter when the div is inside an iframe.

Here is the code of the guider:

```
    guiders.createGuider({
    attachTo: '#'+thisId,
    buttons: [{name: "Ok", onclick: function(){
closeEdit();
    guiders.hideAll();
    }
    }],
    description: "<input value='new text'>",
    id: "guiderToChangeParameter",
    position: 3,
    title: "title",
    width: 400
    }).show();
```

If thisId refers to a div id inside the page, the attachTo works.

If thisId refers to a div inside an iframe, the guiders show but **not attached to the div**.

Is this normal behavior for the guiders.js library? is there a way to really attach to the div inside an iframe?

jsfiddle showing attachTo working: http://jsfiddle.net/y3mzP/1/
jsfiddle does not allow iframe so I cannot reproduce unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect any JavaScript to be able to access the iFrame, not just guiders.js.  If you want to have an element on a parent page positioned near an element on the parent page, you'll have to use iFrame message posting (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to have a script on the inside relay the target element's x and y position to the script on the parent frame.

In your case, you could also create a transparent div absolutely positioned on the parent page such that it is approximately where you expect the inner element to be.  Then have Guiders attach to that transparent div.